# Eclipse shows error, but project compiles and executes

Tags: c++, eclipse, c++11

I'm working in a Eclipse MARS C++ project. The following code compiles and executes perfectly even though Eclipse keeps showing some errors.

The code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ratio>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    typedef std::chrono::duration<int> seconds_type;
    typedef std::chrono::duration<int,std::milli> milliseconds_type;
    typedef std::chrono::duration<int,std::ratio<60*60>> hours_type;

    hours_type h_oneday (24);
    seconds_type s_oneday (60*60*24);
    milliseconds_type ms_oneday (s_oneday);

    seconds_type s_onehour (60*60);
    hours_type h_onehour (std::chrono::duration_cast<hours_type>(s_onehour));
    milliseconds_type ms_onehour (s_onehour);

    std::cout << ms_onehour.count() << "ms in 1h" << std::endl;
}
```

The errors:

- Symbol 'duration' could not be resolved.
- Type 'std::milli' could not be resolved.
- Symbol 'ratio' could not be resolved.
- Symbol 'duration_cast' could not be resolved.
- Method 'count' could not be resolved.
- Invalid overload of 'std::endl'.

I think all the errors are about something with the includes.

The message when building:

```
Invoking: Cross G++ Compiler
g++ -D__GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -std=c++11 -MMD -MP -MF"src/Teste.d" -MT"src/Teste.o" -o "src/Teste.o" "../src/Teste.cpp"
Finished building: ../src/Teste.cpp

Building target: Teste
Invoking: Cross G++ Linker
g++  -o "Teste"  ./src/Teste.o   
Finished building target: Teste
```

I've already put `-std=c++11` on PROJECT > PROPERTIES > C/C++ BUILD > SETTINGS > MISCELLANEOUS.

I've already put `__GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__` on C/C++ GENERAL > PATHS AND SYMBOLS > SYMBOLS too.

I've already cleaned and rebuild it, closed and reopened it (project and eclipse), but nothing happens. This is a 1 file project, how can Eclipse find 8 errors in it and still compile and execute it? I think its just the editor messing with me. Can anyone help me to be free from the errors?

Comment: Are you getting actual compiler errors or is it like other IDEs where the line/variable is highlighted somehow and it tells you what it doesn't like about it?

Comment: It is not a compile error. It is just the IDE complaining about the line.

Comment: If your constant variables are not going to change, you should prefix the type with `const`, as in `const unsigned int hours_per_day = 24;`.

Comment: It's nothing about being constant. But thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Don't trust Eclipse, or Visual Studio or any other IDE for that matter. The parser they use to give you "red squiggles" in the editor is *not* the real compiler. It has different bugs, it has different levels of standard compliance, it has *very little* time to parse your code (since it's interactive).
It *will* give false results.

The 'in-editor' parsers are nice, helpful & convenient tools. But they are *not* the compiler proper and they should not be interpreted as more than helpful hints.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the advice. 
But, like I said before, I'm not worried about my code being wrong. It is clearly correct. I'm looking for a solution to make the IDE understand the correctness of the code.